# what is wrong passing a record type as parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following code snippets:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_test1 IS
  TYPE t_rec1 is RECORD(c1 number);
  FUNCTION f1(p1 t_rec1 ) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END pkg_test1;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_test1 IS 
FUNCTION f1 (p1 t_rec1) return varchar2 is 
  BEGIN
    RETURN 'a';
  END f1;
END pkg_test1;

DECLARE
TYPE t_rec IS RECORD (c1 NUMBER);
v_rec t_rec;  
v_var VARCHAR2(15);

BEGIN
v_rec.c1 := 1;
v_var := pkg_test1.f1 (v_rec);
END;
```

When I execute the anonym code, I received the following error:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'F1'

Can someone help me to see the mistake I make, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you declare in your anonymous block looks the same to you, but to Oracle it's a completely independent and incompatible type.

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7DC81088-1265-4C46-A04D-E3AD10BCC04F):

> A RECORD type defined in a package specification is incompatible with an identically defined local RECORD type.

You don't need it though; just use the package type:

```
DECLARE
  -- don't create a new type....
  --TYPE t_rec IS RECORD (c1 NUMBER);
  --v_rec t_rec;  
  -- use the package type instead
  v_rec pkg_test1.t_rec1;  
  v_var VARCHAR2(15);

BEGIN
  v_rec.c1 := 1;
  v_var := pkg_test1.f1 (v_rec);
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=478b2082076ab1b598c2365c5fc351c7)